# Problems using CalendarExtender in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I included `calendarextender` control using Ajax toolkit in ASP.NET, but I'm facing the following error:

> A `ScriptManager` is required on the page to use ASP.NET AJAX Script Components.

NOTE: When I include `ScriptManager` the compiler does not recognize it as valid control. I have referenced the "System.Web.Extensions" assembly as well.

How do I use `ScriptManager` in this scenario?

Comment: What is the version of your ajax control toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below Toolkit script manager..
I hope this will help you...

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="smDashBoard" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" CombineScripts="false">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```